# datagrid columns more than one sources for bindind

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, advanceddatagrid, itemssource

Hello I have a datagrid which has 10 columns. The first take their values from the itemsource property of the datagrid. But the last two I want them to take their values from an other source.

To be specific , the item source both times is a list of objects.
I would like to know the way to make the last two colums take their values from different source. Searching around I found that you can't set multiple sources in a datagrid at the same time.

I have been trying to create a new list of objects that can combine both the data I need but because everything is done dynamically through code and not xaml, it keeps crashing the other parts of my programm!

So any ideas on how to bind to to a datagridcolumn different source than the datagrid.itemsource???

I have also tried for every datagridtextcolumn to create a binding, setting the list I want to the binding, setting the parameter I need to the path and then the binding to the column, but I get in every cell the same value

so if I do not explain well enough just tell me and I 'll try to explain better
all advices welcome

Answer (score 1):

Write your own column renderer for your AdvancedDataGrid. Then you can provide whatever values you want at runtime. More info [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_10.html).